# Сравнить первую букву слова с последней

Tags: c, c++

Здравствуйте.

Задача сравнить первую букву слова с последней.

Пример: anna начинается на букву a и заканчивается на букву a итаких слов у нас 2.

Благодарю за ответ. :)

```
void main(){

char str[] = "hello to anna annna";

int total = strlen(str);
int counter = 0;

char temp = str[0];
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++){

    if (str[i] == ' '){
        if (str[0] == str[i-1]){

            counter++;
            i = 0;
        }

    }
}

printf("%d",counter);

}
```

Comment: неверный алгоритм, надо проще быть, запишите первую букву и ищите пробел, сравнивайте предудущую к пробелу букву.

Comment: Вы правы, я так и хочу сделать, допустим, первая буква находится на id 6 слова, последняя - на id 9. Надо каждый раз записывать разные буквы, не получается у меня правильный код:

    h=0

    e=1

    l=2

    l=3

    e=4

    ' ' = 5

    a=6    -> то что нам нужна

    n=7

    n=8

    a=9    -> то что нам нужна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[] = "hello to anna annna and ana test to  ana  ";
    string s; // сюда мы будем помещать найденные слова
    int count = 0; // счетчик слов с одинаковой первой и последней буквой

    // разделяем на слова и помещаем их в строку
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if (str[i] != ' ')       // если это не пробел
            s.push_back(str[i]); // помещаем символы в строку
        else {
            cout << "->" << s << "<-" << endl; // отладка
            // сравниваем первую и последнюю букву найденного слова
            if ((s.size() != 0) && (s[0] == s[s.size() - 1])){
                ++count;
            }
            s.clear();
        }
    }

    // проверяем первую и последнюю букву после последней итерации
    if ((s.size() != 0) && (s[0] == s[s.size() - 1]) && (s[s.size() - 1] != ' ')){
        cout << "->" << s << "<-" << endl; // отладка
        ++count;
    }

    cout << count << endl; // результат

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // puts
#include <string.h> // strtok

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "hello to anna annna and ana test to  ana  ";
    char* i;
    for (i = strtok(str, " "); i != NULL; i = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        int last = strlen(i) - 1;
        if (last != -1 && i[0] == i[last])
        {
            puts(i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```